# My linux server takes more than an hour to boot. Suggestions?

Tags: linux, centos, performance, hard-drive

I am building a CentOS 5.4 system that boots off a compact flash card using a card reader that emulates an IDE drive.  It literally takes about an hour to boot.  The ultra-slow part occurs when Grub is loading the kernel. Once that's done, the rest of the boot process only takes about a minute to get to a login prompt.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

I suspect that it may have to do with UDMA.  Everything IDE-related in my BIOS seems to checkout. The read performance hdparm is telling me 1.77 MB/s. Ouch! (But even at that rate, it still shouldn't take an hour to decompress and load the kernel)

```
 [root@server ~]# hdparm -tT /dev/hdc

/dev/hdc:
 Timing cached reads:   2444 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1222.04 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:    6 MB in  3.39 seconds =   1.77 MB/sec
```

Trying to enable DMA is a no-go though:

```
[root@server ~]# hdparm -d1 /dev/hdc

/dev/hdc:
 setting using_dma to 1 (on)
 HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Operation not permitted
 using_dma    =  0 (off)
```

Here's some command outputs that might help:

**System**

```
[root@server ~]# uname -a
Linux server.localdomain 2.6.18-164.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 04:47:32 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**PCI info:**

```
[root@server ~]# lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
        Memory at fdf00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        I/O ports at ff00 [size=8]
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at fdf80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [90] Message Signalled Interrupts: 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at fe00 [size=32]

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        I/O ports at fd00 [size=32]

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        I/O ports at fc00 [size=32]

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
        I/O ports at fb00 [size=32]

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at fdfff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=32
        I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
        Memory behind bridge: fde00000-fdefffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fdd00000-00000000fdd00000
        Capabilities: [50] #0d [0000]

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR/GH (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 80 [Master])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR/GH (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        I/O ports at <unassigned>
        I/O ports at <unassigned>
        I/O ports at <unassigned>
        I/O ports at <unassigned>
        I/O ports at f800 [size=16]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) SMBus Controller
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 17
        I/O ports at 0500 [size=32]

01:04.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
        I/O ports at de00 [size=256]
        Memory at fdeff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2

01:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
        I/O ports at dc00 [size=256]
        Memory at fdefe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2

01:07.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 19
        I/O ports at da00 [size=256]
        Memory at fdefd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
```

**hdparm ouput:**

```
[root@server ~]# hdparm  /dev/hdc   

/dev/hdc:
 multcount    =  0 (off)
 IO_support   =  0 (default 16-bit)
 unmaskirq    =  0 (off)
 using_dma    =  0 (off)
 keepsettings =  0 (off)
 readonly     =  0 (off)
 readahead    = 256 (on)
 geometry     = 8146/16/63, sectors = 8211168, start = 0

[root@server ~]# hdparm -I /dev/hdc

/dev/hdc:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       InnoDisk Corp. - iCF4000 4GB            
        Serial Number:      20091023AACA70000753
        Firmware Revision:  081107  
Standards:
        Supported: 5 
        Likely used: 6
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       8146    8146
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    8211168
        LBA    user addressable sectors:    8211168
        device size with M = 1024*1024:        4009 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:        4204 MBytes (4 GB)
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 2   Current = 2
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 *udma2 udma3 udma4 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    CFA feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
HW reset results:
        CBLID- above Vih
        Device num = 0
CFA power mode 1:
        enabled and required by some commands
        Maximum current = 100ma
Checksum: correct
```

**Edit:** *It's taking about 5 minutes to just get past the "GRUB loading stage 2..." message.  I've come to the conclusion that the problem is likely either: bootloader, BIOS/firmware, or a hardware issue. I've played with all relevant BIOS settings without any luck and replaced my IDE cable in case I had a bad one.  I have a new compact flash card (a different brand) on order, but it'll be a few days before it gets here.  I'm also currently running Memtest86 to see if I have an odd issue with my RAM.  Once that's done, I'll see if there's a firmware update available for my motherboard.*

Comment: Do you have a separate boot partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved!

Oddly enough, *disabling* UDMA in the BIOS fixed the problem.

Thanks goes to [this Ubuntu thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=615659) for having the answer.  And thanks to everyone here for their suggestions as well!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely dont have the correct driver built in the kernel.
Also, make sure your IDE controller is enabled in the BIOS.

Otherwise, please post the content of /var/log/dmesg

Thanks

Comment: The more I work on this, the more obvious that the problem seems to with the bootloader (or something prior to the bootloader: BIOS or hardware problems) since it's painfully slow before the kernel is even loaded.  Also, if my IDE controller were disabled in the BIOS, I wouldn't be booting, period.

Comment: There is chance it boot, small chances but it still have some, depending on the motherboard, I've had an Aopen doing this after a bios update. Please post the /var/log/dmesg I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

Try the GRUB `testload` command on the kernel file - is that also slow?

Comment: I let it try to boot with that option and it took over an hour to run before I gave up and rebooted.  I get "GRUB loading stage 2..." for about five minutes and then it attempts to run whatever is in grub.conf.  I'm really at a loss here... Doing the DVDROM-based install doesn't take all that long, and I can boot fine if I install to a SATA drive instead.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your disk buffer is very slow!! rest of thing look ok to me..

```
Timing buffered disk reads:    6 MB in  3.39 seconds =   1.77 MB/sec
```

following is from my running server with SATA

```
[root@rajat Rajat]# hdparm -tT /dev/sda 

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   2368 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1184.65 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  198 MB in  3.01 seconds =  65.73 MB/sec
```